# How to obtain columns for rows with values greater than zero in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

Suppose we have a dataframe containing the following frequencies for each user_id (in the columns):

```
   1922 7   233 439  662
 0  0   2    3   0    2
 1  1   0    0   1    1
 2  1   0    4   0    0
```

How does one obtain the columns corresponding to rows with non-zero values like this:

```
     Non_zeros
  0  7, 234, 662
  1  1992, 432, 662
  2  1992, 234
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case do `dot`

```
df['new'] = df.ne(0).dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1]
Out[98]: 
0       7,233,662
1    1922,439,662
2        1922,233
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({1922: [0, 1, 1], 7: [2, 0, 0], 233: [3, 0, 4], 439: [0, 1, 0], 662: [2, 1, 0]})    
df.apply(lambda x: list(df.columns[x!=0]), axis=1)
```

will give you

```
0       [7, 233, 662]
1    [1922, 439, 662]
2         [1922, 233]
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in how you specified 'x' , it should be '[x!=0]' for non-zero values @Ted

Comment: Yes I had a typo originally - fixed now!